# [решено]VS Community 2019 после обновления перестал работать автокомплит путей

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2019, asp-net-core-mvc

В рамках самостоятельного обучения создаю `AspNetCore MVC` приложение. Создал отдельные `partial view` для подгрузки таблиц стилей и файлов js. Использую их в `_Layout.cshtml` как

```
@await Html.PartialViewAsync("CssPartial")
...
@await Html.PartialViewAsync("ScriptsPartial")
```

Внутри каждого, с использованием `HTML` подключал таблицы стилей и js-файлы.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/..." />
...
<script src="~/..."></script>
```

При заполнении `href` или `src` по нажатию на `Ctrl+Space` появлялась подсказка расположения, относительно родительской папки `wwwroot`.
[image: Версия Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community]
[image: Autocomplete пути в script src]
[image: Autocomplete пути в link href]
[image: Autocomplete пути в img src]

После обновления `Visual Studio 2019 Community` с версии `16.5.5` до `16.6.1` перестал работать удобный автокомплит, который делал подсказки пути относительно каталога `wwwroot/`. Теперь подсказки пути начинают выстраивать путь от файла, в котором я нахожусь, а при использовании shortcut `~/` начинает выстраивать путь относительно корня проекта, а не от папки `wwwroot/`

[image: Версия Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community]
[image: Autocomplete пути в script src]
[image: Autocomplete пути в link href]
[image: Autocomplete пути в img src]

Понимаю, что в ходе обновления изменились/уточнились наcтройки VS, либо были добавлены новые шорткаты, о которых мне пока не известно. Прошу помощи у сообщества либо ссылку на текст, который поможет мне понять причину и вернуть все как удобно, т.к. хочется использовать VS на столько, на сколько я его пока изучил.
Заранее спасибо!

P.S.: При использовании автокомплита в новой версии по тем же правилам (`~/wwwroot/css/site.css`) ссылки на файлы не работают. Т.е. ссылка ведет на несуществующее место и файл к странице не подключается, а если вручную прописывать путь относительно каталога `wwwroot/` (`~/css/site.css`) то все работает и проблем в браузере не вызывает.

**UPD**: С обновлением `Vusual Studio 2019 Community`  с версии `16.6.1` до версии `16.6.2` проблема ушла.